# helm-locate で and 条件で検索したい

Tags: emacs

helm-locate でスペースをクエリに含めた場合、その検索は and ではなく or で検索されています
(つまり、より多くの条件を指定するとより多くの候補が表示される。)

これは、非常に使いづらいので、 and 条件で検索したいです。つまり、スペース区切りで検索していくと、候補がどんどん絞られてほしいと考えています。

これは実現できますでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`helm-locate-command` で実際に実行する locate コマンドを指定できますが、そこに `--all` オプションを付与してやると実現できました。